# How to record audio from an application while also routing the audio to an output device?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ffmpeg

I would like to record audio from an application and hear it at the same time.

I created a `.asoundrc` file following [these instructions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA#Recordaudiofromanapplicationwhilealsoroutingtheaudiotoanoutputdevice) and substituting `0` for `<Your Output Device Name>` in the `output` section. That `.asoundrc` creates four named devices: `output`, `loopin`, `loopout` and `multi`. The device `multi` is the one that I should use, but trying to do so results in the following error:

```
aplay -D multi audio.wav 
Playing WAVE 'audio.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
aplay: set_params:1239: Channels count non available
```

The other three devices seem to be good:

```
aplay -D output audio.wav # Executes without error and produces audible sound
aplay -D loopin audio.wav # Executes without error, no audible sound
aplay -D loopout audio.wav # Executes without error, no audible sound
```

What could cause the error message I get and how could I fix it?

Alternatively, a different way for achieving my original goal would also be welcome. I already tried using pulseaudio's virtual output device for simultaneous output to my sound device and loopback, which resulted in audiable and recordable sound, but with heavy stuttering.

Comment: In theory, that `multi` device should support two channels. Show the actual configuration you're using.

Comment: My actual configuration is a verbatim copy of the .asoundrc I linked above, except that I substituted 0 for <Your Output Device Name> in the output section.